# Sketching coordinates of C when it meets the x and y axis

Tags: geometry

The question:

Curve $C$ has the equation $y=(x-k)^2 (x-k+2)$ Where $k$ is a constant and $k > 2$.

Sketch $C$, showing the coordinates of the point where $C$ meets the $x$ and $y$ axes.

I am unsure how to tackle this question. In particular, how to place $k > 2$ correctly into the equation to then draw the curve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image] This is the graph of the function for k=3.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\mathcal{C}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\;:\;y=(x-k)^2(x-k+2)\}$ that is the graphic of the function $f(x)=(x-k)^2(x-k+2)$. In order to draw the graph, let's first understand the intersection with the two axes, i.e. you want the point of $\mathcal{C}$ that have at least one coordinate equal to $0$.

So intersection with $y$-axis are given by posing $x=0$, so the unique point is $(0,k^2(2-k))$; similarly, intersection with $x$-axis are given by finding $x$ such that $y=(x-k)^2(x-k+2)=0$, i.e. $x=k$ or $x=k-2$, i.e. the intersection  with $x$-axe are $(k,0),(k-2,0)$. To draw the graph just notice that the curve $\mathcal{C}$ is defined by a 3rd-degree polynomial, which has a simple zero in $x_0=k-2$ and a zero of multiplicity 2 in $x_1=k$. Hence the graph will touch (as already said) $x$-axis twice. Now $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$. One more information is given by noticing that $f(x)\geq0\Leftrightarrow x\geq k-2$. These information are sufficient to draw a qualitative graph.

If you want more precision you should have to study $f'$ and $f''$.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe
I feel the extrema computation is also required, esp. since its not too difficult:

```
x = k-4/3 (by setting dy/dx = 0, and from that y = (4/3)^3 + 2*(4/3)^2
```

the extrema point being (k-4/3, 160/27)

PS: I am not allowed to comment yet, so posting as a new answer